# Flutter MLKit: TensorFlowLiteObjC.modulemap' not found

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-mlkit

I'm trying to use the flutter [MlKit](https://pub.dev/packages/mlkit#-readme-tab-) to build an on device text recognition app. I have followed the [github page](https://github.com/azihsoyn/flutter_mlkit) instructions and I'm testing out the example project.

I've create both IOS and Android apps on the [Firebase Console](https://firebase.com/) and pod installed all the necessary dependencies.

I have commented out the `use_frameworks` line from the podfile as the instructions state on the MlKit github page.

```
target 'Runner' do
#  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
```

However, this is the error i get:

```
fatal error: module map file '/development/AndroidStudioProjects/imagetextidentifer/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/TFLTensorFlowLite/TensorFlowLiteObjC.modulemap' not found
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'image_picker_modern' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'FirebaseMLModelInterpreter' from project 'Pods')
warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'FirebaseMLModelInterpreter' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'Protobuf' from project 'Pods')
warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'TensorFlowLiteObjC' from project 'Pods')
warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'TensorFlowLiteObjC' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'GoogleAPIClientForREST' from project 'Pods')
```

How can I solve this?

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Greate I also have the same problem, as of now I can tell you how to solve, that will be a temporary solution. Open X code and search IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET, and change 4.3 to 8.0. everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is already 8.0  or higher. However, it still gives me an error? Do I need to set everything to the same version?  @satish

Comment: Actualy, 4.3 error is part of pods file, so change there. from x code.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @satish! I'm not sure what i need to change in the pod file? Also do i change the podfile or podfile.lock?

Comment: @satish, If you could post an answer that would be really helpful :) !

Comment: Open x code and search IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET, cntl+shift, and f, and replace all version with you 8.0, because you set your range is 8.0 to 13.2.99. This solution is temporary,  maybe you need to do it always.